# Dataframe date sorting is reversed. How to fix it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, sorting

So, I have a dataframe (mean_df) with a very messy column with dates. It's messy because it is in this format: 1/1/2018, 1/2/2018, 1/3/2018.... When it should be 01/01/2018, 02/01/2018, 03/01/2018... Not only has the wrong format, but it's ascending by the first day of every month, and then following second day of every month, and so on...
So I wrote this code to fix the format:

```
mean_df["Date"] = mean_df["Date"].astype('datetime64[ns]')
mean_df["Date"] = mean_df["Date"].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Then, from displaying this:

[image: wrong format]

**It's now showing this** (I have to run the same cell 3 times to make it work, it always throws error the first time):

[image]

Finally, in the last few hours I've been trying to sort the 'Dates' column, in an ascending way, but it keeps sorting it the wrong way:

```
mean_df = mean_df.sort_values(by='Date') # I tried this
```

But this is the output:

[image]

As you can see, it is still ascending prioritizing days.
Can someone guide me in the right direction?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort the date just after convert it to datetime since `dt.strftime` convert datetime to string

```py
mean_df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(mean_df["Date"], dayfirst=True)
mean_df = mean_df.sort_values(by='Date')
mean_df["Date"] = mean_df["Date"].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. All answers are fix my problem, but your code is the one giving me exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make it into right format

```
mean_df["sort_date"] = pd.to_datetime(mean_df["Date"],format = '%d/%m/%Y')
mean_df = mean_df.sort_values(by='sort_date') # Try this now
```

Comment: thank you very much. Your answer and the other ones are perfect. They all worked. Thank you thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = "1/1/2018, 1/2/2018, 1/3/2018".split(", ")
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['Date2'] = df['Date1'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df.sort_values(by='Date2')
```

First, I convert `Date` to `datetime` format. As I observed, you data follows `'%d/%m/%Y'` format. If you want to show data in another form, try the following line, for example

```
df['Date2'] = df['Date1'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried your code and it works and it fixes the problem. All answers are correct, including yours. The answer above just happens to give me exactly what I needed. Although, your sample is very well crafted and will be helpful in future lines. Thanks!!!